# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features' - When feature stapling to My Sites

Tags: visual-studio, error, feature, my-site, feature-stapling

I am trying to deploy a feature to My Sites in SharePoint 2010 and nothing seems to be working. I did this perfectly fine on the test environment but can't seem to get it working on the production environment. Basically I keep getting this error:

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature with Id 'd336ba21-03c8-4509-9dc5-a5515b11f670' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope.
```

I am using this exact same project http://sp2010mysite.codeplex.com/releases/view/78702 no changes made to it yet to try and deploy it and I keep getting the error. I looked up the id and its the id for the My Content feature which is in the project so I have no idea why it complains. Also this exact same project works fine in another environment, is it my Visual Studio or SharePoint that' giving this problem?

I know I can do this manually using the management shell but I really want to get to the bottom of this issue.

Thanks for the help!
Tudor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is your production a multi server farm? I think you are facing the following issue:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvarro/archive/2011/11/06/sharepoint-2010-amp-visual-studio-2010-error-ocurred-activate-features-feature-with-id-installed-in-this-farm-cannot-be-added-to-this-scope.aspx

> It turns out that VS 2010 internally implements a call to the method 
>   **SPSolution.DeployLocal** That method is intended for troubleshooting purpouses of wsp files and as you can read on the MSDN documentation
>   it performs a local deployment instead of an immediate deployment
>   (Only to one sever of the farm)

Comment: I guess thats what I will have to do but I have one question, I have tried this and ran the commands Add-SPSolution and Install-SPSolution in the management shell on the server however nothing happens...the CSS isn't applied and I don't really know what the next step is. In central admin I can see it as a farm solution and its deployed but the masterpage it deploys isnt visible in the site settings...whats the step I am missing?

Comment: Nevermind, i figured it out, after deploying it I was looking under site collection features but its actually just site features. Thanks for the help!