# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features'

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2013

I am creating and deploying Visual Web Part on SharePoint 2013 with VS 2013 as Farm Solution.

When deploying  Web Part on the server i get the following error:

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature with Id '8a442317-1158-4994-b265-26499b2def57' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope.
```

Help.!!

Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: Have you tried deploying in debug mode?

Comment: No...i dont know how to do it...will u plz help?

Comment: Are you using CKSDEV? http://cksdev.codeplex.com/

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43025/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-activate-features-when-feature-stapling-to

Comment: @BennySkogberg: No..

Comment: Try to run the UAT Development SharePoint farm with only one server with Visual Studio

Comment: Please make sure Site Url path is also correct in solution, in case you are deploying from visual studio.

Answer (score 4):

When you use Visual Studio to build your visual web part. In the Feature Design mode we you gave the scope of feature  as Farm by mistake and when we try to deploy the solution you will get the error message.

"Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature with Id XXXXXXX' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope".

The resolution is pretty straight forward just the change the scope of the feature in Feature design window as "Web".

If it is multi server farm, check following:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvarro/archive/2011/11/06/sharepoint-2010-amp-visual-studio-2010-error-ocurred-activate-features-feature-with-id-installed-in-this-farm-cannot-be-added-to-this-scope.aspx

Comment: Tried before...still it give following error:                                                      The Project Item "VisualWebPart1" cannot be deployed through a Feature with Web scope.

Comment: Change it to site.

Comment: done...now error is: Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature with Id '8a442317-1158-4994-b265-26499b2def57' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope.

Comment: Are you using farm solution or sandbox?

Comment: farm solution..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585282/sharepoint-2010-deploying-visual-web-part-via-a-feature

Comment: I am using VS 2013...

Comment: what is your target framework?

Comment: Target framework : 4.5

Answer (score 1):

Check, that `package.package` has the correct office/sharepoint version,
e.g. SP2016 16.0, SP2013 15.0. It's hardly noticeable but that could be the reason why the feature doesn't get installed into the sharepoint in the first place.
Developing for multiple Sharepoint Versions on many dev machines with different VS and Office Dev Tools and cloning projects can lead to this mess.

[image: VS Screenshot SP package]

Answer (score 0):

Deploy it using Powershell

```
 Install-SPSolution -Identity MySolution.wsp -local -GACDeployment
```

or

```
Install-SPSolution –Identity MySolution.wsp -GACDeployment
```

Comment: Error: This solution contains resources scoped for a Web 
application and must be deployed to one or more Web applications.

Answer (score 0):

Check the scope of the Feature. It should be scoped to `Site`. Since, the project contains visual webpart, you need to specify `webapplication` paramter if deploying through PowerShell

```
Add-spsolution -LiteralPath c:\WSPNAME.wsp

install-spsolution -identity WSPNAME.wsp -gacdeployment -webapplication http://aissp2013
```

Answer (score 0):

On the project's Properties window, in the SharePoint tab select "No Activation" as Active Deployment Configuration.