# Error occured in deployment step Activate Features

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

[image]Our application team having below error while they are Deploying Feature through Visual Studio.

> Error occured in deployment step Activate Features :Feature with id
>   “X” is not installed in this farm ,and cannot be added to this scope

Comment: If you have any screen shot please provide

Comment: our application team is facing issue while they are deploying  feature through visual studio can any one help on this would be appreciated

Comment: i already shared my screen shot for above error

Comment: Kindly attach screen shot with your question. If possible then try to change the scope of your SharePoint Solution according to your requirement.

Comment: Already we tried this what they are we know at we application level to change scope  they need for site collection level

Comment: we are getting this error while we deploying timerjob

Comment: Did you tried given link in my answer?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have multi server farm

*

> Basically the error happens because VS 2010 do not support features
> activation on multi-server farms. However ,the devil is in the
> details, the exact explanation is in a previous step. It turns out
> that VS 2010 internally implements a call to the method
> SPSolution.DeployLocal
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsolution.deploylocal.aspx
> . That method is intended for troubleshooting purpouses of wsp files
> and as you can read on the MSDN documentation it performs a local
> deployment instead of an immediate deployment (Only to one sever of
> the farm) Therefore, the only solution to avoid the situation is to
> compile the code (build o re-build) , go to the VS 2010 top menu and
> select build -> package. After that a new wsp file will be created on
> the BIN folder of the project.

- 

[Ref1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/calvarro/sharepoint-2010-visual-studio-2010-error-ocurred-activate-features-feature-with-id-installed-in-this-farm-cannot-be-added-to-this-scope)

[Ref2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43025/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-activate-features-when-feature-stapling-to)

Answer (score 1):

The second variant of problem is multiserver sharepoint farm (several webfrontend). 
In my case on dev.enviroment used 2WFE(sharepoint 2013), then deploy from VisualStudio impossble.
Deploy project from PowerShell or SharepointInstaller.
Debug - connect from VisualStudio.

Answer (score 0):

kindly go through the following URL which has complete solution for your problem

[Server Error: Feature {GUID} is not installed in this farm and cannot be added to this scope](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sowmyancs/2008/04/01/server-error-feature-guid-is-not-installed-in-this-farm-and-cannot-be-added-to-this-scope/)

Comment: Thanku Hardik can you now see the screen shot now they want to deploy that feature sitecollection level is it possibel through Visualstudio

Comment: Use **force** in the feature properties to deploy the solution once.

Comment: Hi Hardik the force feature i didn't find in properties can you help me how find this

Comment: First open the feature where you have defined the scope in your VS solution & press F4 to check its properties. There you will have attribute called **Always Force Install** so make it **true** from **false**.

Comment: ok Hardik with this option any effect on code will take place ie:force

Comment: Not on code but it will install the same feature forcefully on the server.

Comment: Open the solution in Windows explorer.

Go into the folder Features

Open each subfolder

Open each file with *.feature

Comment: Double click on your feature file & it will open that in your right hand side window of VS. On that you will see your application scope so click on that then press F4 & do the rest which i already explained it to you. If you find it worth for you then kindly make my answer helpful for others as well

Comment: Hi Hardk like above mentioned if we delete that feature it will take any effect on code

Comment: Do not delete that feature else it will not deploy anything to server. Feature is the package of all the thing you developed in the solution.

Comment: Actually Hardik we are getting this issue when we are deploying Timer job

Comment: Check the steps here...http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/how-to-create-timer-job-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Thanku Hardik i will try this "force" option i will let you know still i face any error

Comment: Thanks. If you find my answer helpful then please do needful with it.